# Delete/Modify row in one table based on a condition

Tags: oracle, foreign-key, constraint

I have a table structure like

```
 create table EMPLOYE (
    CodeEmploye varchar2(100) not null,
    NAS varchar2(100),
    CONSTRAINT employe_pk primary key (CodeEmploye)
);

create table SALAIRE (
    CodeEmploye varchar2(100) not null,
    Mois number not null,
    CONSTRAINT salaire_pk primary key (CodeEmploye, Mois),
    CONSTRAINT salaire_code_employe_fk FOREIGN KEY(CodeEmploye) REFERENCES EMPLOYE(CodeEmploye)
);
```

I want to add a constraint where I should not be allowed to modify/delete a row in EMPLOYE table if the same employee exist in SALAIRE table.

What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: what happens if you delete a row in EMPLOYE table if the same employee exist in SALAIRE table?

Comment: @miracle173 That is what is the question.
Expected behaviour is that we should not be allowed to delete or modify an employe in EMPLOYE table if it exist in SALAIRE table.

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Answer (score 0):

## Prevent Delete

Add "on delete set null" to the FK constraint.  Since the column is `NOT NULL`, this process can't happen.

```sql
 CONSTRAINT salaire_code_employe_fk FOREIGN KEY(CodeEmploye)
    REFERENCES EMPLOYE(CodeEmploye)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
```

## Prevent Modify

What you'll need to do is check for "can you update?" during the `UPDATE` process. (eg within a trigger)

One method would look something like:

```sql
declare
  type CodeEmploye_nt_t is table of SALAIRE.CodeEmploye%type;

  CodeEmploye_nt   CodeEmploye_nt_t;
begin
  select a.CodeEmploye
    bulk collect into CodeEmploye_nt
  from SALAIRE a
  where a.CodeEmploye in ( new.CodeEmploye, old.CodeEmploye )
  FOR UPDATE; -- prevent other from modifying important SALAIRE rows
              -- while you're in the middle of a transaction

  raise some_error;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    null;
end;
```